# Creating Preferences Dialog

Tags: c#, winforms

I have to create a Preference Dialog in WinForms like the one MS office applications uses (as shown in the image)

[image]

I was just wondering what could be the best possible way to create it.

One way is to create the list on left side & panel on right side, Handle on List click event and Change the various dialogs in the Panel control. Is there any in built control for it or any better way of doing this task.

Comment: Why don't you use tabs? this is the same functionality only different by design.

Comment: ListBox on the left, UserControl on the right.  No need to make it complicated or go shopping for a control, this just isn't hard to do.  Post code instead of screenshot if you need help.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered this control found here 
[OptionsView control including Design-time support](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?658658-OptionsView-control-including-Design-time-support), though it use a treeview instead of a listbox as in the image posted.

**Features:**

- Add panels via the Panels property, or via the Add Panel smart tag
- Nodes are added automatically for each panel
- Design-time support, selecting nodes in the designer works.
- Child panels: for any panel you can select the node that should
  parent it, using the ParentNode property.
- Action Lists or Smart Tag windows: open a popup with common
  properties and methods via the [>] button on the top-right corner of
  the control. The main OptionsView has features to Add/Remove panels
  as well as selecting a panel. The individual OptionsPanels have the
  ability to choose a Parent Node as well as select the parent panel
  (or parent OptionsView if the panels correspond to root nodes).

There is no sample code to post, you can find this useful